# Camel jetty endpoint could not be found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel

I've got a problem, i need to send get request to the url. But i got exception:

```java
Failed to create route route1: Route(route1)[From[jetty://https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.... because of No endpoint could be found for: jetty://https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/, please check your classpath contains the needed Camel component jar.
```

Camel route:

```java
from("jetty://" + serverUrl)
      .log("${body}")
      .to("direct:process");

from("direct:process").id("processing")
      .log("Body processed")
      .log(body().toString());
```

P.S
I'm using camel 3.16.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message states, your problem is due to the fact that `camel-jetty` is not in your classpath.

Assuming that you use Maven, simply add the following dependency to the pom of your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jetty</artifactId>
    <version>3.16.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If not you can still download it from [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-jetty/3.16.0/jar).

Comment: Already had that dependency but with test scope :)
Now appeared new problem: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/104.21.4.48:443

Comment: New problem = new question :-) Let's avoid mixing problem in the same question